# How do you pass new props to a manually rendered react component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Provider, {store}, React.createElement(MyJSXComponent, {
    foo: 7,
    bar: true,
  })),
  document.querySelector(".some-class")
)
```

How would I go about passing new props to MyJSXComponent without simply rerunning this code?

Is there something like `React.updateElement(MyJSXComponent, { foo: 9, bar: false })`?

Comment: nah that would make things more complicated. calling "render" is your opportunity to pass new props. alternatively if the new props come from a stateful component, react will automatically call render for you when state changes

Comment: @azium right that makes sense, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props should be given by the parent. The parent of MyJSXComponent is Provider, so in your definition of Provider you should be able to change the value of the props passed down to MyJSXComponent.